# Python Quit on Logical Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, stack-trace, exit

In my code I'm trying to handle a logical error. I want to quit the program with an error code, if I do a `sys.exit(1)` it raises a traceback error, which I don't want.
But, if I do `os._exit(1)` it not the cleaner exit.

My need:
Quit like with `os` with just the error code, but need a cleaner exit like with `sys`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `sys.exit(1)` **anyway**. The standard Python traceback hook in [`sys.excepthook()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) handles `SystemExit` cleanly, no traceback is printed. From the [`SystemExit` exception documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SystemExit):

> This exception is raised by the `sys.exit()` function. When it is not handled, the Python interpreter exits; **no stack traceback is printed**.

Bold emphasis mine.

If your program has a top-level exception handler, don't catch `SystemExit`. Usually you do that by not using a blanket `except:` statement, but by catching `except Exception:` instead.